# Kill Asynchronous thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool

I'm trying to read the HttpResponse.GetResponseStream() Asynchronously

```
 Stream source=myHttpResponse.GetResponseStream();
 IAsyncResult asyncResult = source.BeginRead(buffer, 0, new[] { maxDownloadSize, buffer.Length }.Min(), null, null);
```

But for some reason my application hangs at source.Endread()

```
int bytesRead = source.EndRead(innerAsyncResult);
```

I knew that all the Asynchronous calls rely on Threadpool, but is there any way i can kill the thread,

I did placed few controls to kill the asynchronous operation

1. I have placed an external timer, On Trigger im closing the Stream

   ```
   System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimerCallback, source, Convert.ToInt32(new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0).TotalMilliseconds), 1); 

   private static void OnTimerCallback(Object state)
   {
       Stream stream = state as Stream;

       if (stream == null)
           return;

       try
       {
           stream.Close();
           stream.Dispose();

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           //Log Error
       }

       throw new Exception("Successfully closed the Stream and killing the Thread");
   }
   ```

   It is closing the stream, but for some reason the application is still hung.
2. I have placed an external timer, and closing the asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.Close()

Both the mechanisms seems to be vain, is there any way i can kill the thread.

Basically what i want to achieve is Read from NetworkStream and Save it in FileStream, and it works fine for a while and later it hung at source.EndRead(innerAsyncResult); Reading from Networkstream is asynchronous , where as saving the data to filestream is synchronous.

Actual Code:

```
public static void CopyToStreamAsync(this Stream source, Stream destination,
    Action<Stream, Stream, Exception> completed, Action<uint> progress,
    uint bufferSize)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    Action<Exception> done = exception =>
        { //Completed event handler
         };

    int maxDownloadSize = maximumDownloadSize.HasValue
        ? (int)maximumDownloadSize.Value
        : int.MaxValue;

    int bytesDownloaded = 0;
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = source.BeginRead(buffer, 0, new[] { maxDownloadSize, buffer.Length }.Min(), null, null);

    Action<IAsyncResult, bool> endRead = null;
    endRead = (innerAsyncResult, innerIsTimedOut) =>
        {
            try
            {
                int bytesRead = source.EndRead(innerAsyncResult);

                int bytesToWrite = new[] { maxDownloadSize - bytesDownloaded, buffer.Length, bytesRead }.Min();

                destination.Write(buffer, 0, bytesToWrite);
                bytesDownloaded += bytesToWrite;

                if (!progress.IsNull() && bytesToWrite > 0)
                {
                   //Progress Handlers 
                }

                if (bytesToWrite == bytesRead && bytesToWrite > 0)
                {
                    asyncResult = source.BeginRead(buffer, 0, new[] { maxDownloadSize, buffer.Length }.Min(), null, null);                       
                    asyncResult.FromAsync((ia, isTimeout) => endRead(ia, isTimeout), timeout);
                }
                else
                {
                    done(null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                done(exc);
            }
        };

    asyncResult.FromAsync((ia, isTimeout) => endRead(ia, isTimeout), timeout);
}
```

Comment: Could you include complete (but short) code that shows the issue? And does your application hang forever or just until the file (all files?) is downloaded?

Comment: The application just hang,what i see from the log is that it took one hour to download a particular RSS feed(<10M) and finally it just hung and when i see from VS 2012 i see the thread is waiting for something at source.EndRead(innerAsyncResult). My understanding is that Socket is alive it is not closed